# Buddypress on shared hosting max number of user?

Tags: hosting, wordpress, share

I have a buddypress community on WP 3.1 (no WPMU). People only use the buddypress features, no multi site functionality.

space 40GB
monthly bandwidth 100GB

How long before I need VPS? Or can I upgrade the shared server to unlimited (host does offer unlimited bandwidth/domain/traffic plans)?

VPS would be ideal, but costly for a free community without ads. Or maybe the Amazon media storage?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to answer the questions such as:

- How active is your community? You may have a community but if it's
  dormant , that shouldn't threaten your bandwidth
- What type of content does your community engage? Video and large
  graphics are bandwidth monsters of course... and the like

In my experience, I haven't come across sites that use even close to 50 BG of bandwidth. I have managed wordpress installs with 10k + users and still within the confinements of shared hosting :)

Answer (score 0):

No two shared hosts are alike, so while some may have thousands of domains hosted on a single server, others might have 100, hence better performance, and a higher cost as well.

There is no such thing as unlimited bandwidth or unlimited space, there is usually a hidden clause somewhere saying they can cut you off for using too much, which obviously defeats the purpose.

You'll likely need to move to a VPS when your host tells you that you're using up too many resources.